# Integer comparison as string

Tags: sql, postgresql, comparison

I have an integer column and I want to find numbers that start with specific digits.

For example they do match if I look for '123':

```
1234567
123456
1234
```

They do not match:

```
23456
112345
0123445
```

Is the only way to handle the task by converting the Integers into Strings before doing string comparison?

Also I am using Postgre regexp_replace(text, pattern, replacement) on numbers which is very slow and inefficient way doing it.

The case is that I have large amount of data to handle this way and I am looking for the most economical way doing this.

PS. I am not looking a way how to cast integer into string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a standard principle (IMHO), a database design should use a number type if and only if the field is:

1. A number you could sensibly perform maths on
2. A reference code within the database - keys etc

If it's a number in some other context - phone numbers, IP addresses etc - store it as text.

This sounds to me like your '123' is conceptually a string that just happens to only contain numbers, so if possible I'd suggest altering the design so it's stored as such.

Otherwise, I can't see a sensible way to do the comparison using it as numbers, so you'll need to convert it to strings on the fly with something like

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE CheckVar LIKE '''' + to_char(<num>,'999') + '%'
```

Comment: Good conclusions. I will keep them as text as they are now.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mark this as the most conclusive answer. Other's answers are correct too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a match at the start of the value?
You might create a functional index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON mytable(CAST(stuff AS TEXT));
```

It should be used by your LIKE query, but I didn't test it.

Comment: I tested it like this, it works:

    CREATE INDEX my_index ON mytable(SUBSTR(CAST(stuff AS TEXT), 1, 3));
    ANALYZE mytable;

and this query uses the new index

    SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE SUBSTR(stuff::text, 1, 3) = '123';

-- how the hell do i drop code in comments?

Comment: I tried it and the only thing that works for me is:
create index t1 on table_name((col_name::text) varchar_pattern_ops);

Your solution might work on C locale though.

Answer (score 2):

The best way for performance is to store them as strings with an index on the column and use LIKE '123%'. Most other methods of solving this will likely involve a full table scan.

If you aren't allowed to change the table, you could try the following, but it's not pretty:

```
WHERE col = 123
   OR col BETWEEN 1230 AND 1239
   OR col BETWEEN 12300 AND 12399
   etc...
```

This might also result in a table scan though. You can solve by converting the OR to multiple selects and then `UNION ALL` them to get the final result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems like I still have to stick with numbers as string. I hoped handling integers is more performance wise.
BTW database changes are allowed.